# Ubuntu 22.04.3 stop mouse cursor from hiding when typing

Tags: 22.04, mouse, touchpad, cursor

My Ubuntu 22.04.3 laptop has apparently randomly started hiding my mouse cursor when I type. When I use a terminal, this is fine, because the cursor reappears instantly when I start moving my mouse. However, in Firefox, the cursor ONLY reappears if/when I move my mouse of the dock. This is a fairly new behavior - it might have happened after an update, but I'm not sure. Is there a way to fix this?

I can't find any such setting under the "mouse and touchpad" section of the settings application. I don't recall ever having changed anything even remotely related to this behavior.

Comment: I had the same problem. I have set widget.windows.hide_cursor_when_typing and also widget.gtk.hide-pointer-while-typing.enabled in about:config, similar to what is described in https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/vasp14/mouse_cursor_disappearing/?rdt=33395 Then restarted firefox.
So far it seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this (following the comment on my post) I went into the `about:config` section of Firefox and set the boolean `widget.gtk.hide-pointer-while-typing.enabled` to **false**.

After restarting Firefox, my cursor stopped disappearing while typing.