# Ubuntu 22.04.3 - Cursor disappears intermittently

Tags: 22.04, xorg, mouse, cursor

I'm having an issue where my cursor disappears occasionally. I can reliably cause the cursor to disappear by inputting text into a text box on Firefox, but it also disappears in other (seemingly random) cases.

There are a couple of ways I have been able to get the cursor to come back:

- Move the mouse over the GNOME dash/panel
- Some combination of LCtrl + moving the mouse

Also, when highlighting text, the highlight only appears after releasing the left mouse button (maybe related, minor inconvenience, not concerned about this one)

System details:

- Dell XPS 17 9720
- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Xorg 1.22.1.1
- GNOME 42.9

GNOME Extensions:

- Another Window Session Manager
- ArcMenu
- Dash to Panel
- gSnap
- Notification Banner Reloaded
- Notification Counter
- TopIconsFix

I'm comfy with the terminal, but unaware of what kind of info-gathering would be useful for this issue, so if you notice anything missing please let me know!

Comment: Seems another user of 22.04.3 is having a similar issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491344/ubuntu-22-04-3-stop-mouse-cursor-from-hiding-when-typing